# How to join fetch two associations with JPA/Hibernate

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, jpa, hibernate-mapping

I am new to Hibernate and really need help from you guys....
I have following class:  UserActionPerUserResult

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "user_action_per_user_result")
public class UserActionPerUserResult {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private long id;

    @Column(name = "user_email", nullable = false)
    private String userEmail;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "user_action_id", nullable = false)
    private UserAction userAction;

    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinTable(name="user_action_per_user_result_email_message",
                  joinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="user_action_per_user_result_id", referencedColumnName="id")},
                  inverseJoinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="email_message_id", referencedColumnName="id")})
    @JsonIgnore
    private List<EmailMessage> emailMessages;

....getters/setter....
}
```

In MYSQL, the UserActionPerUserResult is one table and for email Messages, there is another table called as UserActionPerUserResultEmailMessage which has email messages associate with id of the table UserActionPerUserResult.

I have all the data stored in the MySQL table, however I am not able to query it. I need to write a query to fetch the list of emailMessages. I am trying the following, but it is throwing exception.

```
TypedQuery<UserActionPerUserResult> messagesQuery =     entityManager.createQuery(
                    "SELECT e from UserActionPerUserResult e JOIN UserActionPerUserResult.emailMessages e1 WHERE e.id = 1 and e.userAction = 1", UserActionPerUserResult.class);
List<UserActionPerUserResult> resultList = messagesQuery.getResultList();
```

Comment: What is the exception thrown?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try writing the query like this:

```
TypedQuery<UserActionPerUserResult> messagesQuery = entityManager.createQuery(
   "SELECT e from UserActionPerUserResult e JOIN FETCH e.emailMessages em WHERE e.id = 1 and e.userAction.id = 1", UserActionPerUserResult.class);
List<UserActionPerUserResult> resultList = messagesQuery.getResultList();
```

1. The join is using the root entity alias
2. The userAction.id is used against userAction, when matching against a numerical value

Comment: It works with this, but I still cant get the EmailMessages list from the result. When I do, result.getEmailMessages, I get the following exception - failed to lazily initialize a collection of role: UserActionPerUserResult.emailMessages, could not initialize proxy - no Session

Comment: Yes, it works!....thanks a ton, you don't know, how much your quick answer has helped me. Many thanks again!